# custom animations on pepper robot

Tags: pepper

I have some the animation files (behavior.xar) how can i upload them on pepper any play them normally through api?

I copied them into the /apps/animations/ directory and when i try to play them it does not work

animation_player_service.run("animations/Stand/Gestures/My_animation") using this example http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/alanimationplayer-tutorial.html

Do i have to register/install all these animations somehow in order to use them? Can you please guide me in this regard? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use ALBehaviorManager.startBehavior(path_to_animations) for run your behavior. But for me, the best way is to install your application with your animations and not to put on the "standard animations" of the robot.

See for example this application ([git demo animations](https://github.com/mcaniot/demo-animations#demo-animations)). Install it on you robot and play the behavior. You can add a new animation but before to re-install on your robot you need to check the box of your new animation. Just click on properties in choregraphe. You will see this :

[image: Your new animation, Hey_1 , have his] box uncheck. So you need to change it. [image]

Now, click on ok and save the changes. If you want to play your animation, install on the robot and play it with `ALBehaviorManager.startBehavior(uuid_application/animations/name_animation)`. For example here the uuid_application is ***demo_animations*** and the name_application is ***Hey_1*** .

Answer (score 0):

hi thanks for your answer, i tried it but now i get this error when i run  qicli call ALBehaviorManager.startBehavior 'myanimations/myanimations/Disengage/15fps/alpha0.5'
ERROR:  ALBehaviorManager::startBehavior
    behavior myanimations/myanimations/Disengage/15fps/alpha0.5 failed to load:     ALFrameManager::createBehavior
        FMBox::createPythonModule
    _Behavior__myanimationsmyanimationsDisengage15fpsalpha051386748584:/: User class evaluation failed with the error:

('invalid syntax', ('', 1, 88, 'class _29fa2578a53152cebf36d236019353c9(_29fa2578a53152cebf36d236019353c9Generated): def **init**(self): _29fa2578a53152cebf36d236019353c9Generated.**init**(self) pass def onLoad(self): self.oldfps = self.getTimeline().getFPS() pass def onUnload(self): self.getTimeline().setFPS(self.oldfps) pass def onInput_onStart(self): newfps = (self.oldfps * self.getParameter("FPS (%)")) / 100 self.getTimeline().setFPS(newfps) pass def onInput_onStop(self): onUnload() pass\n'))

It works fine when i run the animation through choregraphe

Comment: You shouldn't copy (scp) it manually but instead use choregraphe to install them on your robot. Using the "Robot Application" windows. as seen for instance there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9RFkpI4vjo

Comment: yes i did the same but i get an error when i run it. I can see the behaviors in the apps list on choregrpahe. When i play it directly choregrpahe from the app list some animations play alright but some turn red or give the error i posted above when i run it thourgh ALBehaviorManager.startBehavior

Comment: So something's bad in your behavior. Try open it and copy/paste the key animations in a fresh brand new animations boxes.

Comment: The problem was fixed, i was editing the animations in a file and trying to install them, i think it was the file format or something UTF-8 was causing the issue. Now i can install them and play them from the api as well as choreographe. Thanks for your help